# Open .inf file to add a network adapter driver in Windows 7

Tags: windows, networking, adapter

Basically I cannot open my inf file to install my driver, look: when I find my file, then OK, nothing happens.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to set up the file before adding the .inf file.